# When GWT web application run on linux server, I have the error like this

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, gwt, web-applications

In Console log....

```
06-Jun-2018 14:08:44.397 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
06-Jun-2018 14:08:44.397 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
06-Jun-2018 14:09:30.324 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-11]
            org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log
            Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
            com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException:
            Service method 'public abstract com.nirvasoft.rpmini.shared.attendance.ShiftDataset com.nirvasoft.rpmini.client.controller.attendance.AttendanceController.getShiftDataset(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,int) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException'
            threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.nirvasoft.rpmini.server.mgr.system.ConnAdmin.readConnectionString(ConnAdmin.java:77)
    at com.nirvasoft.rpmini.server.mgr.system.ConnAdmin.getConn(ConnAdmin.java:30)
    at com.nirvasoft.rpmini.server.mgr.attendance.ShiftMgr.getShiftDataset(ShiftMgr.java:182)
    at com.nirvasoft.rpmini.server.app.attendance.AttendanceAppSwitch.getShiftDataset(AttendanceAppSwitch.java:1824)
    at com.nirvasoft.rpmini.server.controller.attendance.AttendanceControllerServlet.getShiftDataset(AttendanceControllerServlet.java:1283)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    ... 27 more
```

[readConnectionMethod is look like....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtxA5.png)

It is work in Window Server but linux server have error in readConnection method

Comment: What do you mean by run ? Host the compiled version in a webserver ? Or run in DevMode ? Or run in SuperDevMode ? If in a webserver, which webserver ?

Comment: Please insert the code of the method as formatted text in the question, instead of posting an image.

Answer (score 1):

At line 76 `l_reg` is still an empty string, so `split` return an empty array. The next line is throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because `l_split[1]` doesn't exists.